# jQuery returns 'undefined' for .val() when one absolutely exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to obtain the `.val()` of a input field within an AJAX loaded box. I absolutely know a value exists, however when I try to access the value using jQuery's `.val()`, it always returns undefined.

(Both these `console.log`s are fired right after each other.)

```
console.log(this.content);
```

[image: Console output for this.content]

---

```
console.log($('#sa', this.content).val());
```

or

```
console.log(this.content.find('#sa').val());
```

Returns 'undefined'

---

Just doing a log on the element shows no value either:

```
console.log($('#sa', this.content));
```

[image]

I'm at a loss on why I cannot access this value.

There's a million of these types of questions, so feel free to mark as duplicate if you know of one that asks exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: does `$('#sa', this.content)` or `this.content.find('#sa')` return the element?

Comment: doesnt this.content need to be a jquery object before you can pull  the find and value methods off of it? ie. `$(this.content).find('#sa').val()`

Comment: @Alp Yes, it does. I've updated my question to show that output. However, James McLaughlin's answer below hit the issue spot on. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jQuery.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for descendants, but the element you're looking for isn't a descendant (it's actually part of the collection.)

Try [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
this.content.filter('#sa').val()
```

Comment: I wonder Does `this.content` has a method called `.filter()` ..? Since it belongs to a jquery object.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen What is `this.content` ..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `this.content` is in my original question. Please look there for your answer.